# longitude and latitude scale

Tags: scale, latitude-longitude

Good morning,
Sorry, maybe the title is not clair.

I have georeferenced data, all these data can be bounded with [80',81'] in longitude and [80',81'] in latitude

my question is : if I want to draw these data in a caneva, did this  imply that the caneva must be square,

I mean if I draw these data in a square of [1000,1000] pixels, did I twist (distortion) these data? if it is the case how can I find the appropriate scale?

thank you.

Comment: What "caneva" (presumably you mean Mapping API) are you using?

Comment: yes I am programming in java, drawing in a jpanel